# Нужно ли в Django собирать статику при каждом изменении

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять как правильно нужно работать со статикой в Django. Ситуация такая:

1. Я скачал проект на локальный компьютер. Внес изменения в js файлы внутри приложения.
2. Запушил изменения на gitlab
3. Выкачал изменения с gitlab на боевой сервер
4. js файл обновился внутри приложения, но не обновился в общей папке static всего проекта.

И пока я не ввел команду manage.py collectstatic ничего не произошло.

В связи с этим вопрос - неужели каждый раз при каждом изменении нужно заново собирать статику из приложений, чтобы применить изменения? Не могу поверить, что это так работает. Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: собирайте статику при изменении статики.

Comment: Всё правильно понимаете